# How do i retrieve 3000 row data at 1 time in REST API using GET

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I have a table name nrtable and has a 3000 rows data. I want to retrieve them at one time. I try to use the chunk method but it's only given me 700 at a time. I want to retrieve all the data at one time is it possible?

```
public function index()
{
    $NrMniDataUploaded = NrMniData::with('user')->chunk(500, function($datas){  
        echo $datas;
        die;                                         
    });

    return response()->json($NrMniDataUploaded);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you simply make a query asking for all the data you need, instead of using chunk?

Comment: My first code ->get() and ->paginate. if the data is only 700 row it's returning the data correctly. But if the data is up to 800 rows there is no return after all. and same on the chunk scenario.

Comment: _"I want to retrieve them at one time"_ then why are you using paginate? Just do `get()` whithout any chunk or paginate since those methods _limits_ your results...

Comment: I said if I used get().  It's only retrieving 500 data row. Paginate is working.  But I'm using Datatables. I want to retrieve all the data in one time. like 5thousand row.

Answer (score 0):

To get all data just call `->get()`;

```
public function index()
    {
        $NrMniDataUploaded = NrMniData::with('user')->get();
        return response()->json($NrMniDataUploaded);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. That's my first code ->get() and ->paginate. if the data is only 700 row it's returning the data correctly. But if the data is up to 800 rows there is no return after all. and same on the chunk scenario.

Answer (score 0):

just return `->get()` method. it will give you all the data

```
return NrMniData::with('user')->get();
```

But if you want to show it in a table, its would be better you paginate it

```
return NrMniData::with('user')->paginate();
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. That's my first code ->get() and ->paginate. if the data is only 700 row it's returning the data correctly. But if the data is up to 800 rows there is no return after all. and same on the chunk scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve using chunk or cursor method . for minimum execution time use cursor .